# Difference between feature, feature set and feature vector

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I learnt that a feature is an individual measurable property of a phenomenon being observed.

Say for example, I am representing a human being.

Then various features could be the age, weight, height, etc. Now if I place these features in a vector, a feature vector is formed. From what I have got, the feature vector (an array), in this case will be having three elements-  The first being the age, then weight and finally the height. Similarly for 'n' individuals, I would be having 'n' feature vectors each having 3 elements.

In this context what is a feature set?

Answer (score 7):

A feature vector is a vector that stores the features for a particular observation in a specific order.

For example, Alice is 26 years old and she is 5' 6" tall. Her feature vector could be [26, 5.5] or [5.5, 26] depending on your choice of how to order the elements. The order is only important insofar as it is *consistent*.

A feature set is a set of all the attributes that you're interested in, e.g. height and age.

The implicit assumption when using this terminology is that your data is *tabular* -- somehow, you have chosen to represent it as a "flat", matrix-like format. But non-tabular data formats, like network graphs, video, audio, images, binary data sequences, ... these all require some amount of engineering to represent as feature vectors.

Answer (score 4):

**Feature:** is a list of numbers eg: age, name, height, weight etc., that means every column is a feature in relational table.

**Feature Vector** is representation of particular row in relational table. Each row is a feature vector, row 'n' is a feature vector for the 'n'th sample.

**Feature Set:** Help to predict the output variable.

Example: To predict the age of particular person we need to know the year of birth. Here Feature Set = Year of Birth.

Normally good feature set can be identified using expert domain knowledge or mathematical approach.

Hope this will help you. Cheers!!!.
[image: Feature_Vector]

Answer (score 0):

From a simple data structures perspective, the difference is that a set has no inherent order and contains no duplicates (c.f. a bag of lottery balls) while a vector has order and may contain any value (similar to an array or one-dimensional matrix).